# Is the British Queen not allowed to sit on a foreign throne?

Tags: united-kingdom

I read on http://www.radiotimes.com/news/2015-03-30/heres-why-queen-elizabeth-ii-didnt-sit-on-the-iron-throne :

> “Apparently the Queen of England [sic] is not allowed to sit on a foreign throne,” explained Benioff during an interview with Late Night host Seth Meyers. “This is an esoteric rule we didn’t know about until that moment.”

Is the Queen of the United Kingdom not allowed to sit on a foreign throne? If so, does that apply to fictional thrones?

Comment: There is no [Queen of England](http://law.stackexchange.com/q/17383/372).

Comment: Tell that to Benioff

Answer (score 5):

There's no law as such; it's just an age-old mark of respect that a visiting Royal not sit on your throne. The Queen has encountered other royal families so it makes sense that she'd know this tradition, and was likely just being humorous on the Game of Thrones set. That or she decided the Iron Throne didn't look very comfy!